# React router concatenating routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have 2 routes for one of my components

```
<Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
<Route exact path='/activities' component={ActivityDashboard} />
<Route path='/activities/:id' component={ActivityDetails} />
<Route
  key={location.key}
  path={['/createActivity', '/manage/:id']}
  component={ ActivityForm}
/>
```

If I'm using each `"/createActivity"`, and `"/manage/:id"` (which is editing form's route) separately it's all fine, but if I'm pressing "create new" button (which supposed to call the `".../createActivity"` route) while in editing form (`".../manage/id route"`), it is just concatenating both routes into `".../manage/createActivity"` which is error in my case, and such page doesn't exist. Here is my whole `ActivityForm` component which is related to these routes as shown in the above piece of code.

```
export default observer(function ActivityForm() {
  const { activityStore } = useStore();
  const { selectedActivity, createActivity, updateActivity, loading, loadActivity, loadingInitial } = activityStore;
  const { id } = useParams<{id:string }>();

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState({
    id: '',
    title: '',
    category: '',
    description: '',
    date: '',
    city: '',
    venue: ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) loadActivity(id).then(activity => setActivity(activity!))
  }, [id, loadActivity]);

  function handleSubmit() {
    activity.id ? updateActivity(activity) : createActivity(activity);
  }

  function handleInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setActivity({ ...activity, [name]: value })
  }

  if (loadingInitial) return <LoadingComponents content='Loading activity...'></LoadingComponents>

  return (
    <Segment clearing>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
        <Form.Input placeholder="Title" value={activity.title} name='title' onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <Form.TextArea placeholder="Description" value={activity.description} name='description' onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <Form.Input placeholder="Category" value={activity.category} name='category' onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <Form.Input type='date' placeholder="Date" value={activity.date} name='date' onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <Form.Input placeholder="City" value={activity.city} name='city' onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <Form.Input placeholder="Venue" value={activity.venue} name='venue' onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <Button loading={loading} floated='right' positive type='submit' content='Submit' />
        <Button floated='right' type='button' content='Cancel' />
      </Form>
    </Segment>
  )
})
```

there are all lines containing Link This one is in the ActivitiesList component navigating to the details page

```
<Button as={Link} to={/activities/${activity.id}} floated='right' content='View' color='blue' />
```

and these 2 navigating to the editing form, and back to the list of all items

```
<Button as={Link} to={/manage/${activity.id}} basic color='blue' content='Edit' /> 
<Button as={Link} to='/activities' basic color='grey' content='Cancel' />
```

And create activity is NavLink

```
<Button as={NavLink} to='createActivity' positive content="Create Activity" />
```

Comment: Sorry, where exactly is the route path concatenating occurring? Other than the `useParams` hook I don't see any `react-router-dom` code. Is there more code you could show us to make your [mcve] more complete and comprehensive? I'd be expecting to see a `Link` component or some `history.push` somewhere that would be effecting a navigation action.

Comment: Please edit your post to include any new code and details.

Comment: Done, also, about your question about "where exactly is the route path concatenating occurring". It only occuring while I am already at ActivityForm component at .../manage/id route and pressing create new button which is always available as it is in my header. Create new route is .../createActivity and for some reason it concatenating in manage/createActivity like replacing the id part with createActivity, that is why I showed whole component (because form component is either returning an empty or filled with item's properties by id form)

Comment: The only thing that seems suspect to me is that the link to create an activity isn't using an absolute path. Try `to="/createActivity"` instead of `to="createActivity`.

Comment: omg I am blind
I've been looking for it for an hour, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any overt issues with the code *other than* it seems the one link to create an activity appears to be using a *relative* path value. Add a leading `"/"` to the path to make it an *absolute* path.

Example:

```
<Button
  as={NavLink}
  to="/createActivity"
  positive
  content="Create Activity"
/>
```